# Can hunting of large specimens of a species make the size and weight of the species tend to be smaller?

Tags: genetics, evolution, zoology, ecology, artificial-selection

Siberian tigers in the wild don't grow as much as they used to be in past (in the 1900s).
Their average weight was measured 176 kg in 2005 study. But it was also said that those tigers observed in study were sick and in conflict to humans.

I think their smaller size is because of low prey density because at that time, hunting of animals that come as tigers' prey was high.

Could it also be because all the large specimens were shot?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please add a reference for the study you are citing — this is both expected practice in science (and on this site) and helpful for providing context for your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any research about this on tigers or any other terrestrial predators, but this is a [well-known phenomenon](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20420-unnatural-selection-fish-growing-up-fast/) in "trophy" animals<sup>1</sup> (i.e. big game hunted for sport) and wild-caught fish<sup>1-4</sup>.

1: [Allendorf, F. W., & Hard, J. J. (2009). Human-induced evolution caused by unnatural selection through harvest of wild animals. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 106(Supplement 1), 9987-9994.](https://www.pnas.org/content/106/Supplement_1/9987)

2: [Heino, M., Pauli, B. D., & Dieckmann, U. (2015). Fisheries-induced evolution. Annual review of ecology, evolution, and systematics, 46.](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/full/10.1146/annurev-ecolsys-112414-054339)

3: [Monk, C. T., Bekkevold, D., Klefoth, T., Pagel, T., Palmer, M., & Arlinghaus, R. (2021). The battle between harvest and natural selection creates small and shy fish. Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences, 118(9).](https://www.pnas.org/content/118/9/e2009451118.short)

4: [Bowles, E., Marin, K., Mogensen, S., MacLeod, P., & Fraser, D. J. (2020). Size reductions and genomic changes within two generations in wild walleye populations: associated with harvest?. Evolutionary applications, 13(6), 1128-1144.](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/eva.12987)